# Android Stopping Runnable Handler on Button Release

Tags: android, handler, runnable, ontouchlistener

I have a `button` that starts running a `Runnable Handler` when pressed and it should `stop` it and return it to starting position when released. The problem is that in the `else if` clause, it doesn't recognize the `runnable` so i cannot call `handler.removeCallbacks()` on it.

```
 playRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
            final int action = motionevent.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                playAudio(index);
                final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        assa.setMinX(orderNr);
                        assa.setMaxX(orderNr+5);

                        graph.invalidate();

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 80);
                    }
                };

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 80);
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                assa.setMinX(0);
                assa.setMaxX(2);
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);  
                //Here it doesnt know what runnable is and I can't make it global.

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is because `runnable` is declared inside another block. Declare it more *global* (it is Java basics BTW. You should pass through Java basic training before proceed with Android.)

Comment: The post originally contained the sentence where I said that I tried making it global but got some errors. Which is why I even made this question since making it global didn't work.

Comment: `making it global didn't work.` I think you did something wrong while making it global. **How exactly** it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

to remove all the runnables at a time.

Comment: Is the method called `16qcsLhcYm4NdG4fVkW2mwfDB8kwpPsYCq()` or stackoverflow changed it?

Comment: sorrry ?? didnt get you

Comment: It cannot resolve method `handler.16qcsLhcYm4NdG4fVkW2mwfDB8kwpPsYCq(null)`

Comment: that's strange, because, I am using same in my project

Comment: Anyways I am not sure why but when I tried to make a global Runnable the first couple of times it gave me an error but now seems to be alrigt.

Comment: well in that can , classlevel variable(global) must work, what error it is giving ?